# Progressbar with percentage in Asynctask Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I am writing a code in which I need to move all file and folders to the sdcard. I used Async task for this purpose. During this activity I am showing a progressbar with percentage on my screen instead of just showing me the "Loading..." popup. But it does not meet my requirement.

```
public class syncMgr extends AsyncTask<String, Long, String> {

public LoginActivity activity;
public Context context;
syncMgr(LoginActivity activity1,Context c)
{
    activity = activity1;
    context=c;
} 

//public ProgressDialog progress; 

   protected void onPreExecute() {
       super.onPreExecute();
       activity.progress = ProgressDialog.show(context,"","Files Downloading, Please Wait...",true);
    }

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    copyFilesToSdCard();
    return null;
}

private void copyFilesToSdCard() {
    copyFileOrDir(""); 

}
private void copyFileOrDir(String path) {
    AssetManager assetManager = activity.getAssets();
    String assets[] = null;
    try {
        Log.i("tag", "copyFileOrDir() " + path);
        assets = assetManager.list(path);
        if (assets.length == 0) {
            copyFile(path);
        } else {
            String fullPath = TARGET_BASE_PATH + path;
            Log.i("tag", "path=" + fullPath);
            File dir = new File(fullPath);
            if (!dir.exists() && !path.startsWith("images")
                    && !path.startsWith("sounds")
                    && !path.startsWith("webkit"))
                if (!dir.mkdirs())
                    Log.i("tag", "could not create dir " + fullPath);
            for (int i = 0; i < assets.length; ++i) {
                publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) 658) * 100));
                String p;
                if (path.equals(""))
                    p = "";
                else
                    p = path + "/";

                if (!path.startsWith("images")
                        && !path.startsWith("sounds")
                        && !path.startsWith("webkit"))
                    copyFileOrDir(p + assets[i]);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.e("tag", "I/O Exception", ex);
    }
}
private void publishProgress(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
activity.progress.setProgress(i);
}
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Long... values) {
    activity.progress.setProgress(values[0].intValue());
}

 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
     activity.progress.dismiss();
     super.onPostExecute(result);
        //return "asdas";
     //return result;
}       
}
```

Here is my Activity Class Code...

```
ProgressDialog progress;
public static final int progress_bar_type = 0; 
 /**
 * Showing Dialog
 * */
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case progress_bar_type: // we set this to 0
        progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progress.setMessage("Downloading file. Please wait...");
        progress.setIndeterminate(false);
        progress.setMax(100);
        progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progress.setCancelable(true);
        progress.show();
        return progress;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to used `publishProgress(int progress)`. that'll update your `Progress`

Comment: What's in `copyFileOrDir`?

Comment: @SimplePlan In which function do i need to write this code?

Comment: the `publishProgress` method has to be called in `doInBackground` and it's elaborated in `onProgressUpdate`

Comment: @ZaidIqbal call  publishProgress inside doInBackground()

Comment: @ZaidIqbal do as Der Golem said.

Comment: @DerGolem it is just the simple function to copy the  assets folder to sd card.

Comment: ... after each call to `copyFileOrDir` (which has to be put in a loop). Or inside `copyFileOrDir` itself, if it contains a loop (you want that each file or folder copied increases the progress and/or the copied bytes count).

Comment: @DerGolem I have implemented the publishProgress method in my method loop 
private void publishProgress(int i) {
 activity.progress.setProgress(i);
 }
But it does not make any change in my output

Comment: @DerGolem i am calling it from my loop which is written in copyFileOrDir Method

Comment: @DerGolem Code Updated Please check

Comment: You put the publishProgress method in the wrong place. It belongs to the AsyncTask, not to the Activity.

Comment: Here is everything well explained, in plain English, easy to follow: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Sorry.... again question updated. Now it is exactly same which i am running

Comment: I am already following this link but i stucked at this point that's why i needed a help.

Comment: it shows me the loading pop up but not progressbar of percentage...

Comment: You are redeclaring the `publishProgress` method, which is wrong. Please refer to the example in the link I posted - there's an example on how to publish a ProgressBar.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the asyncTask initiation code into a worker thread like this?

```
// set progressBar .VISIBLE first

// then...
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        // webview initiation code

    }
}).start();
```

I turn on `progressBar` visibility beforehand and not in `onPreExecute()`.

Here is [how it solved my own problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40767263/1827488) & here are [the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads).